# How can I make this code not print an entire list and just a single name and time

Tags: python

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.runningzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Turtle-Krawl-Overall-Results-2016.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

x=2
while True:
    xpathName = "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['x']/td[4]//text()"
    xpathTime = "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['x']/td[9]//text()"
    name = tree.xpath(xpathName)
    time = tree.xpath(xpathTime)
    print (name), (time)
    x += 1
```

So I'm trying to make this print both the person name and time using the xpath.  For some reason the code prints out an entire list of both the name and time, even though I'm pretty sure the xpath of the Name and Time should print a single name.  If I replace the 'x' part with just a single number, it prints just one name.  But if I tell the code to print 'x' where it replacesx with a different number each loop, it just prints huge lists.

Comment: `while True:` without `break` is a risky practice. You need to terminate your loops somehow.

Answer (score 1):

`'x'` does not interpolate the `x` variable into the string.  You need to do something like this:

```
xpathName = "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[4]//text()" % (x,)
xpathTime = "/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[9]//text()" % (x,)
```

Also, as @grael mentioned, you need to terminate your loop somewhere.

Comment: Awesome man!  Works perfectly, I've been looking for answers for about an hour which is the only reason I actually made an account and posted.  Looks like I need to figure out whatever that  percent does.  Thanks again!

Comment: Look up string formatting for whichever version of python you're using.